# Durandal: unable to parse bindings

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Feeling stupid for asking this question, I've been following John Papas SPA tutorial and am having view binding issues.
I've tried to to take the same approach as he has with regards to structure in the application.

My Repo/dataservice:

```
define(function (require) {
var http = require('durandal/http');
var model = require("viewmodels/model");

var getShifts = function (observableShifts) {

    observableShifts([]);

    return http.get("api/shift/").then(querySucceeded);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        var shifts = [];
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            var s = new model.shift(item);
            shifts.push(s);
        });
        observableShifts(shifts);
    };
};

var shiftRepository = {
    getShifts : getShifts
};

return shiftRepository;

});
```

My model:

```
define(function () {

var shift = function (dto) {
    this.start = ko.observable(dto.Start);
    this.end = ko.observable(dto.End);
    this.employeeId = ko.observable(dto.EmployeeId);
    this.shiftId = ko.observable(dto.WorkingShiftId);
    this.userName = ko.observable(dto.UserName);
    return this;
};

var model = {
    shift: shift
};
return model;  
});
```

my viewmodel:

```
define(function (require) {

var shiftRepository = require("repositories/shiftRepository");

var shifts = ko.observableArray();

var vm = {
    activate : activate,
    shifts: shifts,
    title: 'My shifts'
};
return vm;

function activate() {
    return shiftRepository.getShifts(shifts);
}

});
```

my view:

```
<div>
<h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
<span data-bind="text: shifts().length"></span><span> found</span>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Shifts</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: shifts"></tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: userName"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I can see that two items are returned and I can also see the expected properties.
This is a dump from Chrome console:

> ["Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError:…me is not defined;↵Bindings value: text: userName", "views/shifts", Object]
>   0: "Unable to parse bindings.↵Message: ReferenceError: userName is not defined;↵Bindings value: text: userName"
>   1: "views/shifts"
>   2: Object
>   **moduleId**: "viewmodels/shifts"
>   activate: function activate() {
>   shifts: Object[0]
>   **ko_proto**: function (initialValue) {
>   _latestValue: Array[2]
>   0: shift
>   employeeId: function observable() {
>   end: function observable() {
>   shiftId: function observable() {
>   start: function observable() {
>   userName: function observable() {
>   **proto**: Object
>   1: shift
>   length: 2
>   **proto**: Array[0]

What am I doing wrong? I've tried to change the way I map the properties of the dto objects to observables similar to Papas approach, but the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
Doing this in my view works!:

```
<section data-bind="foreach: shifts">
    <article>
        <span data-bind="text: userName"></span>
    </article>
</section>
```

So obviously I was being not too clever with the table construct, can anyone explain to me what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding is right only your HTML is messed up.

You have **closed the `tbody` before the `tr`**. So KO will repeat the empty `tbody` and tries to bind `userName` on the main viewmodel and not on the `shifts` items.

So you just need to fix your HTML and it should work fine:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Shifts</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: shifts">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: userName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```